# DatePicker Widget does not take up entire AlertDialog on Nexus 6

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I have a DatePickerFragment that uses a very simple custom layout. The layout takes up the entire alert dialog on smaller devices (HTC One m7), but does not on the Nexus 6. Does anyone know why the DatePicker does not take up the entire width of the Nexus 6 Alert Dialog or where to begin troubleshooting? Thank you!

Nexus 6 (notice that date header does not fill the entire alert dialog)

[image]

HTC One m7

[image]

dialog_date.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_date_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:calendarViewShown="false">
</DatePicker>
```

onCreateDialog() of DatePickerFragment

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                 .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        mDatePicker = (DatePicker)
  v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_date_picker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                 .setView(v)
//                     .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                         int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                         int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                         Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                         sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                     }
                 })
                 .create();
        }
```

Comment: There were some suggestions to use match_parent, but the alertdialog is rendered the same whether match_parent or wrap_content is used.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: I don't have a Nexus 6 to test this on anymore, but i changed the dialog_date.xml file to have android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: I did that and it didnt seem to help, I am running my 6p at a higher dpi than default but it also seems to show this way in the UI preview, and landscape works perfectly?

Comment: Verify you don't have multiple layout files for different resolutions. Use match parent as the layout_width and layout_height of the DatePicker.  Lastly, look at the layout of the DatePickerFragment and verify that there are no padding/margins there.

Comment: @clint I can confirm I only have one layout, it even shows like this in the layout editor, interestingly I have a time picker setup exactly the same way and it fits fine

Comment: @dazza5000 : Are you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this to work using the suggestion from nitzanj, but I switched how I created the DatePickerDialog and it works as expected now. The complete source is below. The key difference is in onCreateDialog.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    public static final String EXTRA_DATE =
            "com.amicly.acaringtext.date";

    private static final String ARG_DATE = "date";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode, Date date) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);

        getTargetFragment().
                onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The reason is AlertDialog takes more space than the child DatePicker.

Make sure to use dialog theme (ex. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`) without `.Alert` suffix.

Comment: Thank you for this short and concise information. Really boon. :)

Answer (score 4):

Alert dialog has some strict (weird?) rules governing it's size. I'm not sure how to actually solve it, but there's a workaround - Once the dialog is shown you can force it's width to match the date-picker's width. This solved it for me, hopefully it'll work for you too:

> ```
> public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     ...
>     final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
>             ...
>             .create();
>
>     alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
>         @Override public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
>             WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
>             final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
>             lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
>             final View picker = window.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_date_picker);
>             lp.width = picker.getWidth();
>             lp.height = picker.getHeight();
>             window.setAttributes(lp);
>         }
>     });
>
>     return alertDialog;
> }
> ```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! wish I knew why it didn't fit normally, but this solution totally works, thanks again :)

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. still experimenting to see if I can find a solution. Cheers!

Comment: @dazza5000 It is important to use the `android.app.AlertDialog`, **not** the `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`

Comment: The `final Window window = *getDialog()*.getWindow();` is not offered / shown in my option.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is bashing their head against the wall about this (I certainly was after six hours of dealing with it), then this will probably work for you.

Instead of using an AlertDialog with a DatePicker inside it, use a DatePickerDialog. Not only is it much easier to set up, but it actually displays as expected.

Example usage:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

new DatePickerDialog(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.style.DatePickerDialogCustom,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                            dateTime = new DateTime(
                                    year,
                                    month + 1,
                                    dayOfMonth,
                                    dateTime.getHourOfDay(),
                                    dateTime.getMinuteOfHour()
                            );
                            etDate.setText(dateFormatter.print(dateTime));
                        }
                    },
                    dateTime.getYear(),
                    dateTime.getMonthOfYear() - 1,
                    dateTime.getDayOfMonth()
            ).show();
```

The months are offset by 1 because the DatePicker returns month values between 0 and 11.

For the style, do NOT use an Alert Dialog style. This is actually what causes the original issue. If you do not need a custom style, just remove it from the constructor (do not use null). If you are using a custom style, then simply make a new style in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogCustom" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePickerCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerCustom" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I do not know if the same issue plagues TimePickers, but if it does I imagine a similar solution will work.